# How to use selenium module?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, driver

This is what I have so far. I want to open the instagram using selenium

```
#code should be inside three backticks
from selenium import webdriver

class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")

InstaBot()
```

Comment: Please mention your aim and where you got stuck

Comment: Sorry, my aim is to first open instagram webpage. It does not run at all.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2GBO_QjRlo&t=134s This is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

    with Chrome() as driver:
        driver.get('https://instagram.com')
        ... #  Add logic here...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have the chromewebdriver

Install Webdriver manager using pip command

> pip install webdriver-manager

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")
InstaBot()
```

Comment: I ddi this: pip install webdriver-manager and ran that code above, but it doesnt work.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'. Do I have to refresh the page and how? Once it is installed using pip, where does that module go?

Comment: in which editor are you running your python scripts

Comment: In windows the directory will be **C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager**

Comment: Pycharm and then later I downloaded Anaconda. I am using a Mac.

Comment: If you're using pycharm then you must inherit the global packages in your virtual environment, if you' re using anaconda then just change the python intrepretar from default to your local python intrepretaur

Comment: How do I  change the python interpreter from default to local python interpreter?

Comment: in which ide do you want to change the python intrepretar